# Overriding class instance with new members

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Say I have a simple class `AClass` with a public member `f1` which can be overridden. What are the ways to define a new instance of `AClass` with another member `f2`, short of duplicating the source code of `AClass`? Toy code below:

```
class AClass a where
    f1 :: a -> Int

data Val = I Int

instance AClass Val where
  f1 x = 0

  -- the method below can't be added as it is not public member of AClass
  -- f2:: a -> Float
  -- f2 x = 0.0
```

I looked around but I didn't find any clear examples on how to do it (i.e., examples I could understand well - clarity is relative). What are the possible ways? Closure, newtype declaration or something else? It will be helpful to demonstrate the technique with above toy code - you can change `data` declaration etc. (e.g., replace it with a `newtype` wrapper around `Int`) but the only thing immutable in above code is class declaration of `AClass`. This is because the assumption is the class has already been written by a library writer, and so, I can't touch it. The end result should be another toy code which inherits the goodies of `AClass`, and adds `f2` member.

There will be caveats of course, in overriding classes like this. But, it helps to know what is possible, and how.

**-- Update --**

Working code below - Credit to Ben and mergeconflict for coming up with the solution - there were few missing pieces - filled in below:

```
class AClass a where
    f1 :: a -> Int

class (AClass a) => BClass a where
    f2 :: a -> Float

data Val = I Int

instance AClass Val where
   f1 _ = 0

instance BClass Val where
   f2 _ = 0.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?

You have a type `Val`, which you make an instance of `AClass`. You can define any number of functions that use `Val` that have nothing to do with the class. Just stop trying to define them in the `instance` declaration.

If what you're expecting is to be able to have one particular instance of `AClass` that has an extra `f2` function, which you then use in functions that use `AClass` instances and have them be able to call `f2`... that's absurd. By definition, the only things that are known to be common to all `AClass` instances are the things declared in `AClass`. If all you know about some value is that it is a member of a type that is an instance of `AClass`, you can't do anything with it that you can't do with all instances of `AClass`. You can't call anything extra that's particular to certain instances.

If you want to create a *new* class that supports all of the operations that `AClass` does as well as `f2`, and have `Val` be an instance of that new class... then you just do that.

```
class AClass a => AnotherClass a where
    f2 :: a -> Float

instance AnotherClass Val where
    f2 x = 0.0
```

Comment: yes, a class that supports operations of AClass, and does f2 would work. But, if I try your approach, I get error about f1 not being visible member of AnotherClass. The implementation of both f1 and f2 are left to instance, and that is where the error comes from.

Comment: `class AClass a => AnotherClass a where ...` indicates that type `a` must be an instance of `AClass` before it can be an instance of `AnotherClass`.  If you haven't made such a declaration, that would be your error.

Comment: @sal Are you actually intending to have several instances of `AnotherClass` with different implementations of `f2`? If it's just `Val`, it would be much simpler to just implement `f2` directly on `Val` and type your other code with `Val` rather than `AClass`. You can still use `AClass` functionality if `Val` is known to be an instance of it.

Comment: @Ben, I am planning to have several instance declarations, each providing their own implementations of f1 and f2.

Answer (score 5):

Your question doesn't really make sense in Haskell:

> Say I have a simple class `AClass` with a public member `f1` which can be overridden.

If you're thinking about "classes" with "public members" that can be "overridden," you're thinking in object-oriented terms.  The code that you've shown doesn't represent those concepts at all.  See Tony Morris's post ["Type-classes are nothing like interfaces."](http://blog.tmorris.net/type-classes-are-nothing-like-interfaces/)

A *type class* defines a *concept* (in the [C++ sense](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html), if that helps at all).  That concept consists of some set of functions, for example:

```
class Eq a where 
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

... but no actual behavior or implementation of those functions.  There's nothing to "override" here.  Data types that *model* this concept will provide instance declarations, like:

```
data Integer = {- ... -}
instance Eq Integer where 
  x == y =  x `integerEq` y

data Float = {- ... -}
instance Eq Float where
  x == y =  x `floatEq` y
```

So you can implement polymorphic algorithms like:

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual a b c = (a == b) && (b == c)
```

Now, getting back to your question, you can also define type classes that model a *more specific concept* than some previously-defined type class.  For example:

```
class (Eq a) => Num a where
  (+), (-), (*) :: a -> a -> a
```

So, there are instances of `Eq` that are not instances of `Num`, but all instances of `Num` must be instances of `Eq`.  In your example, you might want something like this:

```
class AClass a where
  f1 :: a -> Int

class (AClass b) => BClass b where
  f2 :: a -> Float

data Val = {- whatever -}
instance BClass Val where
  f1 _ = 0
  f2 _ = 0.0
```

Again, `Val` isn't "inheriting goodies" per se, it's just saying it's an instance of `BClass` and thus also an instance of `AClass`.  But this is obviously toy code...

Comment: Nice job picking up on the OP's OO thinking

Comment: @mergeconflict, yes, I am trying to, in your words, "model more specific concept than the previously defined type class". The last snippet of the code you posted is relevant to solving this issue (and similar to the one posted by Ben). The problem is that I can't implement f1 in instance declaration for Val because the compiler complains about f1 not being a visible member of BClass. So, how do we let the instance declaration implement f1 and f2?

Answer (score 4):

You should keep in mind that Haskell is not object-oriented, and Haskell typeclasses are not very much like classes in the object-oriented sense.

You can simply define a function `f2 _ = 0.0`.  It will not be a member of typeclass AClass, unless you add it to the definition -- but why do you need it to be?

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, I am not asking it from OOP perspective. The question is about what is possible in Haskell, and how.